# using document.registerElement to create a custom non-HTML node

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I'm trying to serialize some Text nodes which have custom properties (such as id) which need to be retained in the serialized form.

From looking at [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/), it looks like the best approach might be to wrap each Text element with a special tag that contains the custom properties. For instance:

```
<P>some text</P>
```

might serialize as:

```
<P><custom-text id='node27'>some text</custom-text></P>
```

Of course, when I deserialize I *could* go through and get all instances of the "custom-text" tag and manually replace each with a Text node with the custom properties present.  But I am reading that it is possible to create a custom constructor for the tag, which leads me to believe that I could maybe have this conversion done automatically during the parse stage, which would eliminate the need to re-write the document when done.

However, I am a bit fuzzy on how I would do this.  I can specify a prototype as the second argument to `document.registerElement`, so I figured I would just set the prototype to create a Text node, with a getter and a setter to handle the custom id property:

```
var textId = document.registerElement('custom-text', {
    prototype: Object.create(Text.prototype, {
        id: {
            get: function() { return this.id; },
            set: function(value) { this.id = value }
        }
    })
});
```

But when the `custom-text` tag gets parsed, it doesn't create a text node, it creates an HTML node.  I'm using Chrome 33, and `registerElement` exists in the `document` object, which is supposed to be all I need to check.  I would try creating a function wrapping the Object.create call to try to put an alert or something to see if it is being hit, but I don't see documentation for what the value of prototype is supposed to be anywhere.

Comment: As far as I'm aware `text nodes` don't have attributes, unlike elements. So I don't see how `document.registerElement` would help you. I'm a little confused about `I'm trying to serialize some Text nodes which have custom properties (such as id)`.

Comment: @Xotic750 I need (for example) an id for each Text node.  Since Text nodes don't have such a property/attribute I am creating such a property, e.g. `var txt = document.createTextNode('some text'); txt.id =someid`.

Comment: And how are you performing serialisation of the DOM or the text nodes?

Comment: @Xotic750 that will depend on how de-serialization works. To avoid registerElement issues, I may just wrap all text nodes with a `custom-text` tag as they are created and leave it like that, although that will require a bit of extra overhead.

Comment: Assuming that you will do something like `document.body.outerHTML` then `var txt = document.createTextNode('some text');
txt.id = 'someid';` is not going to work for `id` Wrapping text nodes with elements that have the attributes will be the only way to go, that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom element should be based on the HTMLElement prototype (or a HTMLSpanElement prototype):

```
var textId = document.registerElement('custom-text', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
    })
})
```

No need to add an Id attribute since it already exists.